# Como mostrar a data atual durante o carregamento da página

Tags: javascript, front-end, dom, back-end

Estou querendo exibir a data atual em uma determinada *div* durante o carregamento da página, eu já fiz um esboço funcional do código, porém estou utilizando o *button*. Segui o código:

```js
function formataData(data = new Date()){
   var dia = data.getDate(); 
   var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
   var ano = data.getFullYear();

   if(dia.toString().length == 1) dia = '0'+dia;
   if(mes.toString().length == 1) mes = '0'+mes;

      return dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;
} 
    
document.getElementById("btnData").addEventListener("click", function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("localData").innerHTML = formataData()
});
```

```html
<p>Exibindo data atual.</p>

<button id="btnData">Exibir Data >></button>

<div id="localData" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
```

Comment: Poderia trocar essa função por um simples `new Date().toLocaleDateString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta vc colocar o evento **onload** na função e retirar o evento **onclick** do botão.

```js
function formataData(data = new Date()){
   var dia = data.getDate(); 
   var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
   var ano = data.getFullYear();

   if(dia.toString().length == 1) dia = '0'+dia;
   if(mes.toString().length == 1) mes = '0'+mes;

      return dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;
} 

window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("localData").innerHTML = formataData();
};
```

```html
<p>Exibindo data atual.</p>

<div id="localData" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
```

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo que eu precisava!

Comment: Legal Luckas, pode marcar a resposta como aceita para fecha-la no site?

Comment: Sim, pode sim! eu marcaria como útil, mas não tenho pontuação suficiente para tal

Comment: Opa  Luckas é no botão que parece um V embaixo do sinal para baixo, embaixo do 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Script de fácil configuração

> Com esse script você pode setar o mês da forma que mais lhe agradar (Jan, Janeiro etc).

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var d=new Date();
    var mes=new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
    var DataHoje = d.getDate() + "/" + mes[d.getMonth()] + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("DataAtual").innerHTML = DataHoje;
}
```

```html
<div id="DataAtual"></div>
```

> Caso queira colocar o nome do dia da semana (segunda, segunda-feira, etc.)

```js
var d=new Date();
var dia_semana=new Array("Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sabado");
var mes=new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
var HOJE = dia_semana[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + "/" + mes[d.getMonth()] + "/" + d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("DataAtual").innerHTML = HOJE;
```

```html
<div id="DataAtual"></div>
```

Comment: Boa Leo, realmente ele é prático e de fácil configuração como mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um onload no `<body>`

Veja o código o baixo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="mostrarHora()">


 <p>Exibindo data atual.</p>



    <div id="localData" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>

<script>
    function formataData(data = new Date()){
        var dia = data.getDate(); 
        var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
        var ano = data.getFullYear();

        if(dia.toString().length == 1) dia = '0'+dia;
        if(mes.toString().length == 1) mes = '0'+mes;

    return dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;
    } 


    function mostrarHora() {
    document.getElementById("localData").innerHTML = formataData()};
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, mas não é para mostrar a hora, mas isso também serviria!